# PIXI.js loading the same image multiple times when using a base URL

Tags: typescript, pixi.js, parceljs

I'm developing a game with PIXI.js that will be hosted on URL X and loaded on another website with URL Y.

In order to accomplish this, I use a BASE_URL environment variable that is `''` when local, and `'https://something.web.app'` when not local.

So, I can just do this:

```
import avatar from "../assets/images/avatar.svg";

const BASE_URL = process.env.BASE_URL || '';

loader.add(BASE_URL + avatar);
```

This seems to work, kind of. It seems to do **the correct request first** (with BASE_URL), and **then again** without BASE_URL. In the following picture you can see the erroneous second request:

[image: Problematic second request]

This results in the image not being displayed in the game container.

If I omit the BASE_URL (like it was a few hours ago), **it only requests the image once**.

What can I try, here? I'm using ParcelJS to package this all.

Answer (score 0):

I simply forgot to do `BASE_URL + avatar` somewhere else. Oops.